# Determine neighborhood of coordinate pair

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join, error-000229

I have a data set consisting of coordinates in Los Angeles, which I plotted using ArcMap on a shapefile:

[image]

My goal is to determine the respective underlying neighborhood name as listed in the shapefile for each coordinate pair. I only found the spatial join function which calculated a count of coordinate pairs in each neighborhood. However, I would like to know for each coordinate pair the corresponding neighborhood name.

---

[image]

Under the spatial join it only calculates a count in the shapefile data. My goal is however to have next to each coordinate name the respective "slug" name from the shapefile data.

---

I tried using the spatial join as suggested below, using the following parameters, where sheet 1 are the test coordinate pairs which I would like to have matched the name field of the shapefile to:

[image]

Now I get the following error message, which I don't understand:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is certainly possible, in a number of ways. Please [Edit] the question to specify what have you tried, and what went wrong.

Comment: Spatial Join with Points as target feature and polygons as join features should work or can one point pair be i different neighborhoods?

Comment: Go to menu Geoprocessing - Search for Tools and then type Spatial Join. Select Spatial Join (Analysis). This is the one you should use

Comment: @BERA Thanks, could you please check my edit above and see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error was that I had to save it as a shapefile first. Now it works. many thanks!